# find suspect behaviour

Tags: bash, find

I  am looking, in the current directory, for all files writable by owner and/or group but not writable by all:

```
find . -type f -perm /220 ! -perm /002 -exec ls -l {} \; | tr -d '\.\/' | sort -k 9 -u

-rws--S--- 1 root root 15 Sep 21 16:51 File0
-r--rw---x 1 root root 15 Sep 21 16:51 file01
-rwSr--r-- 1 achille achille 32 Sep 21 16:51 file1
-rwSr--r-- 1 achille achille 15 Sep 21 16:51 file2
-rw-r-Sr-- 1 achille achille 15 Sep 21 16:51 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2254727 Sep 21 16:51 Open2_O
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 183 Sep 21 16:51 test0
```

all seems good but ...

```
find . -perm /220 ! -perm /002 -exec ls -l {} \; | tr -d '\.\/' | sort -k 9 -u

-rws--S--- 1 root    root         15 Sep 21 16:51 File0
-r--r----x 1 root    root         15 Sep 21 16:51 file00
-r--rw---x 1 root    root         15 Sep 21 16:51 file01
-rwSr--r-- 1 achille achille      32 Sep 21 16:51 file1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root    root         15 Sep 21 16:51 File1
-rwSr--r-- 1 achille achille      15 Sep 21 16:51 file2
-rw-r-Sr-- 1 achille achille      15 Sep 21 16:51 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    2254727 Sep 21 16:51 Open2_O
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root        183 Sep 21 16:51 test0
```

without '-type f' switch, there are 2 more unexpected files: file00 and File1

---

```
file -i file00

file00: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

stat file00
  File: file00
  Size: 15          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file

[..]
```

---

```
file -i File1
File1: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

stat File1
  File: File1
  Size: 15          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
[..]
```

---

```
file -i File0
File0: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

stat File0 
  File: File0
  Size: 15          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
[..]
```

---

file00 and File1 (the faulty ones) look like other files (like File0 for example), so :

1. why do file00 & File1 appear in the second instance (without -type f switch)!?
2. why do their perm do not correspond to the ones I am looking for?

Thank you folks indeed !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m guessing that there’s a *directory* (which could even be `.`, the current directory) which matches your criteria, and it contains `file00` and `File1`. The `ls` command on the directory shows its contents, regardless of their permissions, and your filtering `sort` hides the duplicates (from multiple `ls` invocations).

You’ll get a better idea of what’s going on if you add `-d` to the `ls` invocation, and remove the `sort` (temporarily).

Comment: or, if using GNU or FreeBSD find, use `find -ls`

Comment: The `find` expression `-ls`, it was introduced by SunOS-3.5 in 1986 and is today available everywhere except for AIX and HP-UX even though not mentioned by POSIX. `-perm /xxx` however is non-portable.

Comment: @Stephen: There are no subdirs and ls -ld . gives drwxr-xr-x

Comment: @achille yes, so `.` matches, which explains what you’re getting.

Comment: @ilkkachu, the `-ls` option is available on any relevant system (including AIX, HP-UX and Solaris), but the `-exec` will behave differently for directories (which is the point of Kitt's answer).

Comment: As for when the `-ls` option was ***introduced***, that was before SunOS **3.5** (e.g., [3.4](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/sun/sunos/3.4/800-1295-04A_Commands_Reference_Manual_198609.pdf) but the earliest mention I've found is a commit in CSRG a year before (Jun 1985), by Serge Granik.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, yes, `find -ls` would resolve issue, in the same way adding `-d` to `ls` does. Honestly, FWIW, I don't care that much where `find -ls` comes from and wouldn't want to waste time finding out. If I'd said to use `find -ls` without qualification, I'd have gotten a comment that it's not a standard option. But of course the idea was to refer to any version of find that has it, giving those two as examples. Not to claim that it would only be found in those two. FWIW, the version of Busybox I have at hand doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Found a solution: Using the c style -printf '%u - %m - %p\n' instead of -exec ls -l {} \; gives the same result in both cases (and removes duplication issue at the same time).